# Need specific string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2005, trim

I need your help guys.

I am trying to get specific word from the whole string in SQL Server.

I have following string:

'ABC, XYZ'

Need Output : ABC

Now I need only ABC out of whole string.
I tried with Substring and Trim function but couldn't get appropriate output.

Could anyonel please help me?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use patindex
Example

```
select SUBSTRING ('ABC, XYZ',1, PATINDEX ( '%,%', 'ABC, XYZ')-1)
```

Comment: @ Viktor Bardakov: its working perfectly... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select SUBSTRING('ABC, XYZ',CHARINDEX('ABC','ABC, XYZ'),case when CHARINDEX('ABC','ABC, XYZ')>0 then 3 else 0 end),
```